# HSRP - 2 separate Virtual Router for Distribution and WAN?

Tags: router, network-core, wan, hsrp

I've got 2 Core-Multilayer-Switches connected with each other with two cables (trunks). They are also connected with the distribution-switches (and each switch is connected with both core-switches).

Each core-switch is also connected with two WAN-Router(routed-ports) (It's not shown in my "drawing" that EACH core-switch is connected to BOTH WAN-Routers).

```
  (WAN 1) O                  O (WAN 2)
           \                /
      Core1 []============[] Core2
            |  \        /  |
            |   \      /   |
            |    \    /    |
         DISTRIBUTION SWITCHES
```

Now, I want to form HSRP with the core-L3-Switches for the distribution Switches and the WAN-Router.
Do I have to configure 2 virtual router? Or are the wan-router and the dis-switches accessing the same virtual router? And what connection type is used between those core-switches (trunk or normal ip-interfaces)

Comment: Are your core switches layer-3 switches?

Comment: yes - I wrote "Multilayer-Switches" instead of Layer-3 Switches

Comment: Are the links from the core switches to the WAN routers routed links, and do both core switches connect to both WAN routers?

Comment: I think you mean access switches, not distribution switches. Your core switches are your distribution switches (they connect to the access switches).

Comment: No, I really mean core-switches. That's how it is wished (not by me).

Comment: So, your distribution switches connect to a bunch of access switches?

Comment: Indeed, yes #longercomment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would do is configure a virtual router for each VLAN. Configure HSRP on The SVIs on your core switches. A host will use the virtual router as the gateway for the VLAN to which it is connected.

Between the layer-3 switches and the WAN routers, you use routing, not HSRP. Routing will fail over much, much faster than HSRP in the case of a failure.

Comment: Yes, I am of your opinion that routing is the better way to go between L3 and WAN. The thing is that it is wished the other way.

Comment: HSRP is for hosts on a VLAN, not for routed links, and you said that you have routed links between the core switches and WAN routers, so you cannot configure HSRP on those links.

Comment: Oh well... I am sorry for that wrong information... I put that in the question wrongly because I wanted to do it that way.... but well, no, they are not routed ports, sorry

Comment: Then how are they connected. Each interface on the WAN router is in a different network. HSRP must be on the same network, it doesn't span networks. You really need to edit the question to include a better diagram, and the router and core switch configurations.

Comment: they are access-links on the core-switch

Comment: What connection type should the connection between the core-switched be? Normal routed ports?